# Understand Impersonate

Tags: sql-server

I did understand impersonate as a command to give one user the rights to jump into the role of another and use his rights.

Lets assume Administrator is an sysadmin of SQL Server.

When I execute the command

```
GRANT IMPERSONATE ON LOGIN::[PC\Administrator] TO [PC\LimitedUser]
```

did I the do the same, like i would have given the limited user sysadmin rights ?

Confusing causes the fact that with the command

```
EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'PC\Administrator'
SELECT * FROM SecretTable
```

the limited user cant access this table.

(Using MS SQL Server 2012)

Comment: I'm not in a position to test but I would have thought that would work too. Though also not be advisable as anyone that can impersonate a sysadmin effectively is a sysadmin.

Comment: Ah explained here https://sqlstudies.com/2014/02/26/impersonating-a-server-level-permissions/